# What is the best way to manage static keys? (TS)

Tags: typescript

In my app I have always the issue to use some keys which are predefined and won't change at all - i.e. they are hardcoded. And I have no real clue which of the options are the best.

Currently I have:

```
export class PermissionKeys {
  public static readonly MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED = 'MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED';
}
```

as well as

```
export enum MyKey {
  MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED = <any>'MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED',
}
```

and in the final code I want to compare something like `this.checkKey=MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED`. With the `enum` I need to append always the `.toString()`. With the `readonly` strings I need to specify the name and the content (which remains always exactly the same).

Anybody have better ideas to manage hardcoded keys?

Comment: Just plain object. No static-only classes. No mangled enums. This is TypeScript and not Javascript, by the way.

Comment: Yeah... I see... thx for the hint ... I thought the feature are quite the same

Comment: Enums https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: The features are the same for the most part since TS is a superset of JS, but the context is different. And enums are TS-only. You should keep in mind how types will be applied in TS, so the approaches may differ a lot.

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan Not really - I guess - cuz `Direction.right` needs to be compared with `"right"` ==> how to get the string "right"?

Comment: lets assume `this.checkKey = "right"`, then you can check it as `Direction[this.checkKey] === Direction.right`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information on your use case, I'm not sure what's the best way for you to go.  You can use string enums:

```
export enum MyKey {
  MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED = 'MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED', // no <any>
  OTHERKEY = 'OTHERKEY',
  ETC = 'ETC'
}

class Something {
  checkKey: MyKey;
  someMethod() {
    if (this.checkKey === MyKey.MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED) {
      // do something
    } 
  }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to repeat yourself and know that the values and keys will always be equal, you can just use a constant plain object:

```
function sameValuesAsKeys<K extends string>(...values: K[]): {readonly [P in K]: P} {
  const ret = {} as {[P in K]: P}
  values.forEach(k => ret[k] = k);
  return ret;
}

export const MyKey = sameValuesAsKeys('MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED', "OTHERKEY", "ETC");
type MyKey = keyof typeof MyKey;

// still works
class Something {
  checkKey: MyKey;
  someMethod() {
    if (this.checkKey === MyKey.MYKEY_NOT_ALL_SPECIFIED) {
      // do something
    } 
  }
}
```

Does that answer your question?  If not, please be more specific about your use case... show some code where you can't get the key you want or where you feel like you're repeating yourself, and I'll update the answer.

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

#### Update 1

Explaining the signature of

```
function sameValuesAsKeys<K extends string>(...values: K[]): {readonly [P in K]: P}
```

The type parameter `K` is some string or union of strings, and the parameter `values` is an array of that type of string.  If I call `sameValuesAsKeys("dog","cat")`, TypeScript infers `K` to be `"dog"|"cat"`.  The return type of `sameValuesAsKeys()` is `{readonly [P in K]: P}` which is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) meaning roughly "an object where each property is readonly and where the value is the same as the key".  So if I call `sameValuesAsKeys("dog","cat")`, the return value is of type `{readonly dog: "dog"; readonly cat: "cat"}`.

Comment: Yeah, thx this helps - in way to prevent double naming and double definition - although some other (minor) issues arises in the IDE. Anyway this solution has the benefit to forward the content of the variable directly. This helps to avoid double definition. (Although I have to admit that I do not fully understand the generic code - ROFL). Thx

Comment: Added some explanation for the signature of `sameValuesAsKeys()`, not sure if it clears anything up for you.

Comment: Yeah, thx for the extra explanation - which helps for digestion. Also thx for providing the link to the mapped types - which I'll like to have as an update for TS :-) I greatly appreciate your help/assitance

Comment: Although quite old I've asked a follow up in https://stackoverflow.com/q/73163236/325868

Answer (score 0):

Working demo https://es6console.com/j7ajnnma/ . Please follow steps to see results :

1. open your bowser console
2. choose compiler => "typescript"
3. click "transform"
4. click "run"

---

#### Code from demo:

```
enum Direction {
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}

/* Trues */
var value: any = 'Right';
console.log(`'Direction[value] === Direction.Right' => ${Direction[value] === Direction.Right}`);

value = 3;
console.log(`'value === Direction.Right' => ${value === Direction.Right}`);

/* False */
value = 'Up';
console.log(`'Direction[value] === Direction.Right' => ${Direction[value] === Direction.Right}`);

value = 1;
console.log(`'value === Direction.Right' => ${value === Direction.Right}`);
```

Comment: I personally like this solution but unfortunately I cannot work with it cuz I need to process somewhere else in an encapsulated way the equality of the string, i.e. I need the string value itself :-/