# Eslint & Typescript: named functions as const or class constructor: how to transform?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am using frequently the code of [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098752/325868) I've asked for:

```
function sameValuesAsKeys<K extends string>(...values: K[]): {readonly [P in K]: P} {
  const ret = {} as {[P in K]: P}
  values.forEach(k => ret[k] = k);
  return ret;
}
```

Since time goes on the Eslint from Angular nowadays complains about that function.

`Use const or class constructors instead of named functions`

I tried

```
const sameValuesAsKeys:<K extends string>=(...values: Array<K>): {readonly [P in K]: P} => {
  const ret = {} as {[P in K]: P};
  values.forEach(k => ret[k] = k);
  return ret;
}
```

which fails since it cannot find `K` and the approach like

```
const TEST={
    sameValuesAsKeys(...values: Array<K>):<K extends string> => ({readonly [P in K]: P}) => {
```

fails as well. Any hint how to format it properly to avoid the error from ESlint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a syntax error. This compiles:

```
const sameValuesAsKeys = <K extends string>(...values: Array<K>): {readonly [P in K]: P} => {
  const ret = {} as {[P in K]: P};
  values.forEach(k => ret[k] = k);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the quick proposal and fix.